# How can I know the number of polygons in a selected area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

How can I know the number of polygons in a selected area in QGIS?

Can I use the Select features tool if so how?

Comment: Do you already have a selection or do you want to make one?

Comment: I whant to make a selection and know how many polygons are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have made a selection, just open the attribute table and note the numbers at the top.

[image]

The dialog box's title will tell you not only the number of features currently selected but also the total number of feature in the layer. You may also be interested in the 'Show selected only' box which, if checked, will only list the currently selected features in the attribute table.